# Please help with Identifying my diode?

Tags: diodes, components, identification

I am having trouble identifying this component. I think its a diode. But I am not sure since I hardly know much about electronic components.

The Component says "22-16 U2" and then has a symbol on it.

I know 22-16 is actually a wire gauge or size. But I am not sure if that is what it is referring to.

Any help would be appreciated.

When I tested it with the diode setting on my multimeter it showed a voltage drop on both directions.
So Me thinking its a diode ... thinks its gone bad... but is it really a diode, and what do the markings mean?

I have a photo of it. But I guess since I am new to this forum I do not have enough reputation points... Bummer But I can email the photo to anyone willing to help.

Comment: You can host your picture on imgur.com or similar and point to it from your question. Or at least, give the package type — leaded or SMT, dimensions, etc. — and the voltage drops you found with the diode tester.

Comment: Standard item naming convention would indicate an IC when using U(n). A Diode would be D(n) while a Capacitor would be C(n). A picture would really help.

Comment: You are very welcome to email me the photo and I'll add it to your question - apptechnz at gmail dot com. Or post on Imgur or similar site as Warren says.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an SS16. 60V, 1A Schottky diode.

[Datasheet here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88746/ss12.pdf)

Does the package look something like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a tantalum capacitor to me: 22uF, 16 V. The package looks a bit like the diode in Russell McMahon's answer, but is often beige instead of black.

[image]